# How to Sort Auth Page in Firebase Console by Date Created?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-console

I use the Firebase Console and was wondering if there was a way to sort the auth tab by date created so that I can see my newest users first?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to sort the users in the Auth panel of the Firebase Console. Good feature request though.

Comment: How do I officially request a feature? @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: You've already done so by asking about it here. We're simple that way. I haven't heard this one very much yet, so it's not high on anyone's radar at the moment. But I'll keep an eye out for other mentions of it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen we need this, it's so hard to test any hypothesis if we can't filter or order our users... thanks!